# Regex not working in url for Spring-Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, spring-boot-test

I have below URL's int one resource.

```
Get URL = /class/{name}/" + "/student" + "{path: (?:/count|)}" + "/details
Post URL = /class/abc/student/details
Post URL = /class/abc/student/count/details
```

I wrote testcases using above URL's.

```
1. Get /class/abc/student/details
2. Get /class/abc/student/count/details
3. Put /class/abc/student/details
4. Put /class/abc/student/count/details
```

Test-cases 1 and 2 passed. But For Test-cases 3 and 4 giving "405 Method not allowed".